# Memberexpression on collection item

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

I am currently struggling to get a method done using a memberexpression on the items within a collection.
I know how to write a memberexpression holding directly the member of the collection but how can I tell it to use its underlying type.

```
private Collection<TestClass> collection { get; set; }
DoSomethingWithCollection(collection, () => collection.Count);

private void DoSomethingWithCollection(Collection<TestClass> collection, MemberExpression member)
{
    foreach(var item in collection)
    {
        //use reflexion to get the property for each item 
        //based on the memberexpression and work with it
    }
}
```

How would I need to rewrite this code that the call of DoSomethingWithCollection can hold a Memberexpression of the underlying type of the collection, so from the "TestClass"?

Comment: Let me make sure I understand: let's say your `MemberExpression` points to a property `Name`.  In this case, you simply want to read the `Name` property from each item in the collection?  Because in your use case, you pass in a lambda that reads a property on the collection itself (`Count`).

Comment: Thats correct. I am only interessted in a property of the class inside the collection. I provided the Count as an example, because thats how I know to do it with the collection "directly" but I dont know how to do with the underlying types.

Comment: Do you want to be able to pass in a lambda as the second parameter, as in your example?

Comment: Yes, that would be preferable. To sum it up I just want a way to remove a string telling me the property of the items within the collection. so instead of DoSomethingWithCollection(collection, "Name"). I desired some compile safe way, that when I rename the property of my "TestClass" that the string wont result in errors.

Comment: Then you should just accept a delegate as a value accessor callback and not bother using expression trees.  See Thomas's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your comments, you asked about setting properties as well.  Perhaps what you are really looking for is a more generalized solution like a `ForEach` operator that performs some action for every element in a collection:

```
public static void ForEach<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Action<TSource> action)
{
    if (source == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
    if (action== null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("action");

    foreach (TSource item in source)
        action(item);
}
```

Now you could read a property:

```
items.ForEach(item => Console.WriteLine(item.Name));
```

...or set a property:

```
items.ForEach(item => item.Name = item.Name.ToUpper());
```

...or do anything else:

```
items.ForEach(item => SaveToDatabase(item));
```

You could write this extension method yourself, but it also a part of the Interactive Extensions, which extends LINQ with several features from the Reactive Extensions.  Just look for the "Ix Experimental" package on NuGet.

Answer (score 3):

You could use generics to achieve that more easily and efficiently:

```
private void DoSomethingWithCollection<TClass, TProperty>(
    Collection<TClass> collection,
    Func<TClass, TProperty> extractProperty)
{
    foreach (var item in collection)
    {
        var value = extractProperty(item);
    }
}
```

Here is how you'd use it (considering your collection items have a "Name" property):

```
DoSomethingWithCollection(collection, item => item.Name);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer looks very nice, and alot easier than my reflecion call of the properties. Just a quick question is it also possible to assign a value with this or is it limited to get a value?

Comment: Yes, but you will need a different delegate type (one which accepts a target object and a value) like `Action<TClass, TProperty>`.  Then you can pass in `(item, value) => item.Name = value`

Comment: @MikeStrobel: I have tried to change the code to your suggestion, but I fail doing so. My method has the following signature: DoSomethingWithCollection<TClass, TProperty>(IEnumerable<TClass> collection, Action<TClass, TProperty> setProperty) (as you recommended). My call is now: DoSomethingWithCollection<TabAccountLang, string>(this.TabAccountLangs, (lang, value) => lang.TextAccount = "asdfasdf"); - VS told me I had to include the <TabAccountLang, string> directly. But I dont know how the setProperty paramater is used correctly. setProperty(item, ???); whats the second parameter now (value?)??

Comment: Yes, you would invoke the callback with two arguments: the target object (the item in the collection) and the new property value.